# what are the lenses still available for ubuntu 20.04 unity desktop environment?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses

i want to install multiple lenses that would let me search the web through my unity dash. can you tell me what lenses are still available today in 2022 ? and tell me how can  I install them? no links please, answer in details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the command

```
apt list | grep unity-scope-
```

to show all unity lenses that are available in the software sources connected to your system.

```
apt search unity-scope-
```

will also provide a small description.

Alternatively, you may install the venerable software management tool `synaptic` to search and list packages. `aptitude`  works quite similarly, but is console based, i.e., it runs in the terminal.

You may want to check which official software sources are enabled in "Software and Updates", "Ubuntu Software"  tab.

Comment: omg, thank you so much for your answer!

Comment: lol. unity crashed after i tried to install them. and I had to reinstall it. after I did that I saw under ''source'' in the unity dash that the scopes were installed but they still didn't work

Comment: i guess scopes weren't made for unity 20.04. the only  additional scope that I installed that worked is the calculator scope.

Comment: I would expect they work well with the version of Unity shipped in the Ubuntu repositories, otherwise there is a lack of quality control there!